# Customers get discount, but didn't set a coupon or cart rule

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

my customers get a lot of discount when they were logged in (around 70%). But i never made a coupon code or cart rule.

Anyone know where i can delete that?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be a cart rule. Please recheck your backend.

Answer (score 0):

Please run the below commands if you have disabled all cart rules and coupons and still apply the discount. and same for the opposite like you have created coupon and cart rules and did not applicable for discounts.

**php bin/magento setup:upgrade**
**php bin/magento cache:flush**